# Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 80)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to implement a sequence tagging model with the LSTM. Just for example I have 200 sentences in which, each token has a 1024-dim embedding. I also padded all the sentences to 80-dim vectors. So, I have an input matrix with shape (200,80,1024).

I also padded the targets. I have for each token of the sentences a tag. So the shape of my y is (200,80).

I tried with the LSTM in this way

```
from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers.merge import add
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Bidirectional, Lambda

max_len = 80 
input_text = Input(shape=(max_len,1024), dtype=tf.float32)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True,
                       recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(input_text)
x_rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=512, return_sequences=True,
                           recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(x)
x = add([x, x_rnn])  # residual connection to the first biLSTM
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(x)
model = Model(input_text, out)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(np.array(full_embeddings), y,batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 80)
```

Could anyone explain me the problem? I'm quite new to Keras and Neural Nets and I'm not able to understand the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your final output layer is `time distributed`, it has 3 dimensions. Your targets, `y` should also have 3 dimensions. Reshape your `y`

```
y = np.expand_dims(y, -1)
```

to have a shape of `(200, 80, 1)`